# .htaccess rewrite rule for category/subcategory

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want use rewrite rule for categories

But my code work for first category only

My code :

```
RewriteRule ^category/([^/]+)/$ category.php?url=$1 [NC,L]
```

My Test :

```
http://nnn.com/category/a/ -> work
http://nnn.com/category/a/b/ -> not work
http://nnn.com/category/a/b/c/ -> not work
```

Comment: @anubhava thank you, but `print_r($_GET);` return only first value.

Comment: Then use: `RewriteRule ^category/(.+)$ category.php?url=$1 [NC,QSA,L]`

Comment: @anubhava work like a charm, thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may change your rule to this:

```
RewriteRule ^category/(.+)$ category.php?url=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

`.+` pattern instead of `[^/]+` will allow 1+ of any characters including `/` in parameter `url`.